# Is there a way to generate SearchVector field content on runtime?

Tags: django, postgresql, vector, full-text-search

Model have a SearchVector field and a CharField content field.

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(...)
    vector = SearchVectorField()
```

When `content` field changed, `vector` field is updated by query below:

```
AModel.objects.filter(id=xx).update(vector=SearchVector('content'))
```

If I fetch the `vector` field and lookup in to it, the content of the field is looks like below:

> "'2':38 '3':32 '4':26 '5':20 'bskl':14,19,25,31,37 'ck':2
> 'clb':13,18,24,30,36 'club':4 'f':1 'fck':11,16,22,28,34
> 'clb-bskl':10,15,21,27,33 'kargo':9 'pv':12,17,23,29,35 'trt':6
> 'tsrt':7"

I want to generate this data in python/django without reading `vector` field from db.

I took a look at the SearchVector class but I can't figured out how it can be possible.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve, could you elaborate bit further. Do you want SearchVector to automatically update itself on database level?

Comment: I made change in content of the what I want line to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "on the runtime", but if you're referring to getting the search vector itself using Django, you would have to

```py
from django.db import connection

content = 'hello world'

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM to_tsvector(%s)', [content])
    ts_vec = cursor.fetchone()[0]

print(ts_vec)
```

That would output

```
'hello':1 'world':2
```

Comment: Yes I want to generate data without made any change/read operation on the relevant field. So, you say, I have to run a query anyway. But this query will only give what I want without touching the field.